# HTML5 Canvas: Why are these squares not the same size?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Recently, I was playing around with the HTML5 Canvas and I ran across the problem seen here - https://jsfiddle.net/6buwndz6/.

Here's the code:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#e74c3c";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0,15,15);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.fillStyle = "#e67e22";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(60,14,75,29);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

The only differences between the two squares (that I can see) are the colour codes, and the starting position of the `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` parameters. However, in both cases the `w` and `h` parameters are `15` more than the `x` and `y` parameters. So, apart from being positioned in different places, they should be the same size (15 x 15), right?

Nope :P

The orange square is significantly bigger than the red one, and I can't see any real reason as to *why*. Just to clarify, the red square is the intended size.

I'm using Chrome 49 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Any suggestions?

Comment: MDN Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect

Comment: no dude height and width depends on the exact values you give for h and w they are not relative to x and y values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you're thinking the arguments for `ctx.rect` is `x1, y1, x2, y2`; but, it is, in fact, as you say: `x, y, w, h`.

Therefore: `15x15 != 75x29`

Comment: Thanks. I'm so used to using APIs that use `x`, `y`, `w`, `y` and not `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` that I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 3):

W means width and H means height. Therefore, both cases should be 15

ctx.rect( 0, 0, **15**, **15**);

ctx.rect( 60, 14, **15**, **15**);